How to sync the controls of storybook and manual state changes
I am new to storybook and frontend development.
I have this checkbox.tsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './checkbox.module.css'; // Ensure this import points to the correct CSS module

interface CheckboxProps {
  label: string;
  checked: boolean;
  onChange: (checked: boolean) => void;
}

const Checkbox: React.FC<CheckboxProps> = ({ label, checked, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.checkbox}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.checked)}
        className={styles.checkboxInput}
      />
      <label className={styles.checkboxLabel}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;

checkbox.stories.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { StoryFn, Meta } from '@storybook/react';
import Checkbox from './checkbox';

export default {
  title: 'UI Components/Checkbox',
  component: Checkbox,
} as Meta<typeof Checkbox>;

const Template: StoryFn<typeof Checkbox> = (args) => <Checkbox {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  label: 'I agree to the terms and conditions',
  checked: false,
  onChange: () => {},
};

export const Checked = Template.bind({});
Checked.args = {
  label: 'I agree to the terms and conditions',
  checked: true,
  onChange: () => {},
};

When I run storybook, toggling the control is checking and unchecking the checkbox. However if I manually check the checkbox, the control is not toggling to true and manually unchecking is not toggling the control to false. What should i do about it
When I run storybook, toggling the control is checking and unchecking the checkbox. However if I manually check the checkbox, the control is not toggling to true and manually unchecking is not toggling the control to false. How should I go about it?

The checked state is not an internal state of the Checkbox component but rather controlled as a prop from the parent component. When you toggle the checked prop using Storybook UI, the part of passing the right prop value is taken care of.
In most cases this behaviour is fine since you only want to showcase how the checkbox looks in the Default state and you show the Checked state separately.
If it is really required to allow the user to interact with it then you would need to provide a parent component which would help with controlling the checked prop. The Template function can be used for this purpose.
You can update the Template function to:
const Template: StoryFn<typeof Checkbox> = (args) => {
    const [ checked, setChecked ] = useState(args.checked);

    // handle toggle from storybook UI
    useEffect(() => {
        setChecked(args.checked);
    }, [args.checked])

    // handles toggle via user interaction
    const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked(checked => !checked);
    };

    return <Checkbox {...args} checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />
};

